# Collision detection for diagonal movement

Tags: java, collision-detection

The collision detection system I have for my small game sort of works. It's able to tell when the player goes straight into a wall. However when the player goes diagonal, it clips through the wall. I really don't understand where the issue is occurring.

The below code is from the class that handles the player:

```
public void run()
    {
        running = true;

        while(running)
        {

            //Get the key/s pressed
            controls.update();


            //Move down
            if (controls.down)
            {
                movePlayerDown(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
            }
            //Move up
            if (controls.up)
            {
                movePlayerUp(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
            }

            //Move right
            if (controls.right)
            {
                movePlayerRight(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
            }
            //Move left
            else if (controls.left)
            {
                movePlayerLeft(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
            }



            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(this.sleep);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


    public void movePlayerRight(int dx)
    {
        //Gets the tile at what would be the new coordinates of the player
        Tile tile  = currentLevel.getTile(this.thisPlayer.getX() + dx + this.thisPlayer.getWidth(), this.thisPlayer.getY());
        //IF the tile is null or not solid then the player is actually moved
        if (tile == null || !tile.isSolid())
        {
            this.thisPlayer.setX(this.thisPlayer.getX() + dx);
        }
    }


    public void movePlayerLeft(int dx)
    {
        //Gets the tile at what would be the new coordinates of the player
        Tile tile = currentLevel.getTile(this.thisPlayer.getX() - dx, this.thisPlayer.getY());
        //IF the tile is null or not solid then the player is actually moved
        if (tile == null || !tile.isSolid())
        {
            this.thisPlayer.setX(this.thisPlayer.getX() - dx);
        }
    }


    public void movePlayerDown(int dy)
    {
        //Gets the tile at what would be the new coordinates of the player
        Tile tile = currentLevel.getTile(this.thisPlayer.getX(), this.thisPlayer.getY() + dy + this.thisPlayer.getHeight());
        //IF the tile is null or not solid then the player is actually moved
        if (tile == null || !tile.isSolid())
        {
            this.thisPlayer.setY(this.thisPlayer.getY() + dy);
        }
    }


    public void movePlayerUp(int dy)
    {
        //Gets the tile at what would be the new coordinates of the player
        Tile tile = currentLevel.getTile(this.thisPlayer.getX(), this.thisPlayer.getY() - dy);
        //IF the tile is null or not solid then the player is actually moved
        if (tile == null || !tile.isSolid())
        {
            this.thisPlayer.setY(this.thisPlayer.getY() - dy);
        }
    }
```

The next block of code is the getTile() method:

```
public Tile getTile(int x, int y)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < worldTiles.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < worldTiles[r].length; c++)
            {
                if (worldTiles[r][c] != null)
                {
                    int right = worldTiles[r][c].getX() + worldTiles[r][c].getWidth();
                    int bottom = worldTiles[r][c].getY() + worldTiles[r][c].getHeight();

                    if (x > worldTiles[r][c].getX() && x < right && y > worldTiles[r][c].getY() && y < bottom)
                    {
                        return worldTiles[r][c];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to add collision detection code, issue lies in there, please post that. Also how are you moving diagonally ? as above code lists only up-down-left-right controls.

Comment: If the user is holding the up and right key, then the player moves in a diagonal motion.

Comment: From the programs point of view it's still combination of `up` and then `right` key. It just appears to you that it's moving diagonally because it's fast, but it won't matter to the CPU as it's way faster. That means error is in your collision detection code. Which can't handle an `up` followed by `right` key or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

a) you dont define a condition where tile==null - thats for further consideration

b) the logic to test for each event is as follows - one key at a time

```
        //Move down
        if (down)
        {
            movePlayerDown(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
        }
        //Move up
        else if (up)
        {
            movePlayerUp(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
        }

        //Move right
        else if (right)
        {
            movePlayerRight(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
        }
        //Move left
        else if (left)
        {
            movePlayerLeft(this.thisPlayer.getSpeed());
        }
```

The sleep should be removed from there because it ties down the program and possibly missing events.

c) The events should be fired from the key event handler and not have some one to go there and fetch them.

In fact I would reverse the whole logic as follows:

```
void keyPressed(event) {
  sendEvent(event)
}
```

where

```
void sendEvent(event) {
  if(event==down) ......


.......

}
```

replaces your while loop.